# How to to get the value of an auto increment column in postgres from a .sql script file?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In postgres I have two tables like so

```
CREATE TABLE foo ( 
    pkey   SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name   TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE bar (
   pkey SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   foo_fk INTEGER REFERENCES foo(pkey) NOT NULL,
   other  TEXT
 );
```

What I want to do is to write a .sql script file that does the following

```
INSERT INTO foo(name) VALUES ('A') RETURNING pkey AS abc; 
INSERT INTO bar(foo_fk,other) VALUES 
               (abc, 'other1'),
               (abc, 'other2'),
               (abc, 'other3');
```

which produces the error below in pgAdmin

```
Query result with 1 row discarded.
ERROR:  column "abc" does not exist
LINE 3:                    (abc, 'other1'),

********** Error **********

ERROR: column "abc" does not exist
SQL state: 42703
Character: 122
```

Outside of a stored procedure how do a define a variable that I can use between statements? Is there some other syntax for being able to insert into bar with the pkey returned from the insert to foo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can combine the queries into one. Something like:

```
with foo_ins as (INSERT INTO foo(name) 
                 VALUES ('A') 
                 RETURNING pkey AS foo_id)
INSERT INTO bar(foo_fk,other)
SELECT foo_id, 'other1' FROM foo_ins
UNION ALL
SELECT foo_id, 'other2' FROM foo_ins
UNION ALL
SELECT foo_id, 'other3' FROM foo_ins;
```

Other option - use an anonymous PL/pgSQL block like:

```
DO $$
DECLARE foo_id INTEGER;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO foo(name) 
    VALUES ('A') 
    RETURNING pkey INTO foo_id;

    INSERT INTO bar(foo_fk,other) 
    VALUES         (foo_id, 'other1'),
                   (foo_id, 'other2'),
                   (foo_id, 'other3');
END$$;
```

Comment: very clever use of the with statement :)

Comment: Option 3: use [`currval`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html) if you know the name of the sequence.

Comment: @Erwin: As long as no other sequences are being used in the mean time. I tend to prefer `currval` to cut down on the hidden dependencies.

Comment: @mu: That's correct. But we *know* that no other sequence is being used *in the same session* in this case. I commented on that in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use **[`lastval()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html)** to ...

> Return the value most recently returned by `nextval` in the current session.

This way you do not need to know the name of the seqence used.

```sql
INSERT INTO foo(name) VALUES ('A');
INSERT INTO bar(foo_fk,other) VALUES 
  (lastval(), 'other1')
, (lastval(), 'other2')
, (lastval(), 'other3')
;
```

This is safe because you control what you called last in your own session.

---

If you use a [**writable CTE**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) as [proposed by @Ihor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19337709/939860), you can still use a short `VALUES` expression in the 2nd `INSERT`. Combine it with a `CROSS JOIN` (or append the CTE name after a comma (`, ins`) - same thing):

```sql
WITH ins AS (
   INSERT INTO foo(name) 
   VALUES ('A') 
   RETURNING pkey
   )
INSERT INTO bar(foo_fk, other)
SELECT ins.pkey, o.other 
FROM  (
   VALUES
      ('other1'::text)
    , ('other2')
    , ('other3')
   ) o(other)
CROSS  JOIN ins;
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `currval`

```
INSERT INTO foo
  (name) 
VALUES 
  ('A') ; 

INSERT INTO bar
  (foo_fk,other) 
VALUES 
  (currval('foo_pkey_seq'), 'other1'),
  (currval('foo_pkey_seq'), 'other2'),
  (currval('foo_pkey_seq'), 'other3');
```

The automatically created sequence for serial columns is always named `<table>_<column>_seq`

**Edit**:

A more "robust" alternative is to use `pg_get_serial_sequence` as Igor pointed out.

```
INSERT INTO bar
  (foo_fk,other) 
VALUES 
  (currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('public.foo', 'pkey')), 'other1'),
  (currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('public.foo', 'pkey')), 'other2'),
  (currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('public.foo', 'pkey')), 'other3');
```

Comment: how does currval deal with multiple connections to the database, is it unique per connection?

Comment: @ams `currval` is per uniqe per database session (connection) and it will throw an exception if no `nextvall` were called in current session.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name better use `pg_get_serial_sequence(table_name, column_name)` instead of relying on `<table>_<column>_seq` pattern.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko: thanks, I always forget about that function.